# How to use shouldSelect on Hint for React-Bootstrap-Typeahead to detect "enter" and "," keystrokes

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

I have been trying to figure out a way to select hint on "Enter" or "," keystroke but am unable to find any documentation on it. Additionally, I get the following warning, during compilation "Warning: [react-bootstrap-typeahead] The `selectHintOnEnter` prop is deprecated. Use the `shouldSelect` prop on the `Hint` component to define which keystrokes can select the hint." Is there any examples on how to use the shouldSelect on 'Hint'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shouldSelect` prop has the following signature:

```
(shouldSelect: boolean, SyntheticKeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => boolean
```

You can use it to define the conditions under which the hint should be selected. In your case you'd want something like the following:

```
<Hint
  shouldSelect={(shouldSelect, e) => {
    // Select the hint if the user hits 'enter' or ','
    return e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 188 || shouldSelect;
  }}>
  ...
</Hint>
```

Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rbt-shouldselect-example-51s7n